# Proposing a sub project within a main project (tone)

Tags: research-process, postdocs, application-cover-letter

I am writing a project proposal aiming to fit it in main project that is been developed in the faculty I am applying for a postdoc position. Guidance suggests that I need to propose something that will work as a subproject, obviously it needs to show high proximity to the main project. Thus, I wonder, is it wise to show I am willing to negotiate my proposition or I have to make it look like I know exactly what I want to do.

Thanks